# adding items to a headed queue in scheme

Tags: queue, scheme

I am trying to understand the following code for adding items to a headed queue in scheme. The code is taken from The Scheme Programming Language ([Link to the chapter](http://www.scheme.com/tspl3/start.html#./start:h9)).

```
(define make-queue
  (lambda ()
    (let ((end (cons 'ignored '())))
      (cons end end)))) 

(define putq!
  (lambda (q v)
    (let ((end (cons 'ignored '())))
      (set-car! (cdr q) v)
      (set-cdr! (cdr q) end)
      (set-cdr! q end))))
```

I don't understand how this code seems to modify both the queue and the head at the same time. The queue (car q) isn't called in this function at all. If I go through the steps manually, one by one, I can see that modifying (cdr q) simultaneously modifies (car q) but I have no idea why. Here is the terminal output of me adding an item manually (after loading the above code):

```
(define myq (make-queue))
(display myq) => ((ignored) ignored)
(set-car! (cdr myq) 'a)
(display myq) => ((a) a)
(set-cdr! (cdr myq) (cons 'ignored '()))
(display myq) => ((a ignored) a ignored)
(set-cdr! myq (cons 'ignored '()))
(display myq) => ((a ignored) ignored)
```

What particularly baffles me is that the set-car! and the first set-cdr! modify both the list and the head, but the second set-cdr! only modifies the head. If someone could tell me what is going on here I would really be grateful, because no amount of rereading the chapter helps it to make more sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is all because of the `let` inside `make-queue`. The `car` and `cdr` of `myq` refer to the same object. So when you mutate the `car` or the `cdr` you are acting con the same object. But `myq` is not. So mutating it will not affect the other object.

```
(define a '(end))
;Value: a

(define b a)
;Value: b

(define c (cons a b))
;Value: c

c
;Value 15: ((end) end)

(set-car! (car c) 'HI)
;Unspecified return value

c
;Value 15: ((hi) hi)

(set-cdr! (cdr c) '(hello))
;Unspecified return value

c
;Value 15: ((hi hello) hi hello)

(set-cdr! c '(end))
;Unspecified return value

c
;Value 15: ((hi hello) end)
```

Comment: Thank you, this makes it clear what is happening. I still don't quite understand why (set-cdr! (cdr c)) and (set-cdr! c) have such different effects: are they not both modifying (cdr c)? 

If (car c) and (cdr c) refer to the same object, why does (set-cdr! c) manage to modify only the cdr, but (set-cdr! (cdr c)) modifies both car and cdr (through the object they refer to). I know from the result what is happening, but I would never predict it.

Comment: `(set-cdr! (cdr c))` sets the `cdr` of c's `cdr` wich in my example is `b` (which refers to `a`). It mutates `b`, not `c`. `(set-cdr! c)` mutates `c`, changing it's `cdr` from `b` to `'(end)`. I know this is confusing, and hope you can understand it now.